# Angular: how to get url of a resource action?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I have defined an Angular resource like this:

```
app.factory('Files', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/accounts/:account_id/sites/:site_id/files/:file_id');
});
```

To create a new file I would do:

```
var file = new Files($scope.file);
file.$save( $stateParams );
```

How do I get the url used by file.$save (POST /api/accounts/:account_id/sites/:site_id/files) within my controller, with all $stateParams filled in?

EDIT:

I'm trying to upload a file using ng-file-upload. This module requires a url be passed to the upload function:

```
$scope.upload = function (file) {
    var url = 'api/accounts/' + $stateParams.account_id + '/sites/' + $stateParams.site_id + '/files';
    Upload.upload({
        url: url,
        data: {file: file}
    }).then(function (resp) {
        console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
        getFiles();
    }, function (resp) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
    }, function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
    });
};
```

I want to avoid building the url variable by hand. Looking at angular $resource source code I don't think this is possible. Is it?

Comment: I'm not used to ng-file-upload but from what I gather you're supposed to provide additional data in the `data` object, which can hold other fields than the `file`one. I suppose that would answer your requirements to construct a POST request holding a file and other data. You should check out [their Upload service documentation](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/blob/master/README.md#upload-service).

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish what you want you could do a simple refactoring of your code this way:

```
app.factory('fileUrl', ['accountId', 'siteId', 'fileId', function fileUrlFactory(accountId, siteId, fileId) {
  return '/api/accounts/' + accountId + '/sites/' + siteId + '/files/' + fileId';
}]);
```

Now, the factory provides the urls for the files, that way you have only one point in your code where you construct them. Then use like this:

```
var yourFileUrl = fileUrl($stateParams.account_id, 22, 41); //Or whaterver you need
var file = $resource(yourFileUrl);
file.$save();
```

Keep in mind that $resource is by itself a factory, and that you can get it's instances by meanings of calling it with the adequate params.